# "She looked at me, impressed" in search of another word for impressed

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

> She looked at me in _________ [noun implying *impressed*].

But this isn't how I want to word it. 
What I *want* to write, is, "Her eyes widened as her eyebrows raised and she drooped her bottom lip in [enter word for impressed]" And I know it isn't *impression*, please help! What's the word I'm looking for?

Comment: I have modified the sample sentence to match with the explanation.

Comment: Drooping bottom lip doesn't suggest "awe" very well. More like silly or sad.

Comment: Hello (belatedly), Destiny. What have you found in thesauri?

Comment: If her jaw had dropped instead of her lip drooping, I'd have said she was __awe-struck__.

Answer (score 2):

> She looked at me in ***admiration***.

Collins:

> **[admiration](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/admiration)**
>
> uncountable noun [in *NOUN*]
>
> Admiration is a feeling of great liking and respect for a person or
>   thing.
>
> Meg's eyes widened in admiration.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Answer (score 0):

You could say that she looked at you in **amazement.** [TfD defines it as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/amazement)

> A state of extreme surprise or wonder; astonishment.

Of course, this also conveys the idea of being *surprised,* and it is not *always* a positive thing. But it may be appropriate in context.